# Proof of Taylor's Theorem by Indeterminate Coefficients

Tags: taylor-expansion

**Taylor's Theorem - Expansion of** $f(x+h)$.
$$f(x+h)=f(x)+hf'(x)+\frac {h^2}{2!}f''(x)+\ldots+\frac {h^n}{n!}f^n(x+\theta h)$$Where $\theta$ is any value between ero and unity, and $n$ is an integer. For the proof, the book said to assume $f(x+h)$ as an infinite series in $h$, and take the derivative of this. First for $x$, and again for $h$. Then equate the coefficients in the two results.

---

I'm having a bit of trouble in the proof. I understand that if you take the derivative of the LHS first with respect to $x$, then to $h$, the two quantities are equal to $f'(x+h)$.

But if you take the derivative with respect to $x$, the RHS becomes zero.$$f(x+h)=A+Bh+Ch^2+Dh^3+\ldots$$$$f'(x+h)=\frac {d}{dx}\left(A+Bh+Ch^2+Dh^3+\ldots\right)=0$$And with respect to $h$$$f'(x+h)=\frac d{dh}\left(A+Bh+Ch^2+Dh^3+\ldots\right)=B+2Ch+3Dh^2+4Eh^3+\ldots$$This would imply that the coefficients of our original series are all zero.$$\begin{align} & A=0\\ & B=0\\ & C=0\\ & D=0\\ & \cdots\cdots\end{align}$$Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must assume $A = A(x)$, $B=B(x)$, etc. since the RHS is still a function of $x$.

Comment: Ah! So$$f'(x+h)=B(x)+2hC(x)+3h^2D(x)+\ldots$$$$f'(x+h)=A'(x)+hB'(x)+h^2C'(x)+h^3D'(x)+\ldots$$Setting them equal and equating the coefficients to zero, we get$$\left[A'(x)-B(x)\right]+h\left[B'(x)-2 C(x)\right]+h^2\left[C'(x)-3D(x)\right]+\ldots=0$$So$$f(x+h)=A(x)+\frac {h}{1!}A'(x)+\frac {h^2}{2!}A''(x)+\frac {h^3}{3!}A'''(x)+\frac {h^4}{4!}A^{\text{iv}}(x)$$

Comment: @Crescendo Looks good!

Comment: So, just wondering now that I've thought of it, but is leaving everything in terms of $A(x)$ perfectly fine? Or is it preferable to convert it to $f(x)$? And where does the last term come into play?

Comment: @Crescendo $A(x)=f(x)$ trivially (let $h=0$), so you could write it wrt $f(x)$. What last term are you referring to?

Comment: The $\frac {h^n}{n!} f^n(x+\theta h)$. We defined our series to be infinite, so wouldn't that imply that our *original series for* $f(x+h)$ be infinite too?

Comment: @Crescendo I imagine you could use the infinite series result to show the remainder term corresponds to the tail end of the sum.

Comment: I was showing this proof to someone, and they said that you can't prove the expansion like that because the derivative with respect to $x$ and $h$ are two different things.$$\frac {\partial}{\partial x}f(x+h)\ne\frac {\partial}{\partial h}f(x+h)$$How do I reply to that?

Comment: @Crescendo Why should they be different? On the LHS, hold $h=h_0$ constant and differentiate, to get $f'(x+h_0) = f'(x+h)$. On the RHS, do the same with $x=x_0$.